# `direct-vuex` getters has `{}` type with no property but it's filled at runtime

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm implementing my VueJS store using typescript + `direct-vuex` package and have a problem using getters.

The type of `store.getters` is `{}` and has no property. But at runtime it has properties.
The weird thing is that `UserModule.getters` type is correct but the store does not:

**userModule.getters:**

[image]

**store.getters:**

[image]

**store/index.ts:**

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);

const {
  store,
  rootActionContext,
  moduleActionContext,
  rootGetterContext,
  moduleGetterContext,
} = createDirectStore({
  state: {
    CurrentUser: {} as User,
  },
  modules: {
    user: userModule,
    chat: chatModule,
  },
});

console.log(store.getters);
```

**store/modules/user/index.ts:**

```js
export const userModule = defineModule({
  state: {
    userList: [],
    currentUser: {},
  } as UserStates,

  actions: userActions,
  mutations: userMutations,
  getters: userGetters,
});
```

**store/modules/user/userGetters.ts:**

```js
export const userGetters = defineGetters<UserStates>()({
  canUpdateUsers(...args): boolean {
    const { state } = userGetterContext(args);
    console.log("Getters state: ", state);

    return (
      state.currentUser.role === "admin" ||
      state.currentUser.role === "presenter"
    );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After much trial-and-error, I've come up with the following:

```
// store/index.ts
...

// Declare the intersection type of all modules' getters
// This works, because all of the getters are at root at runtime,
// proved by printing the value of `this.$store.direct.getters` from any component
type RootGetters = typeof AccountUserStore.getters &
  typeof CurrentUserStore.getters &
  typeof MessagesStore.getters &
  typeof PermissionStore.getters &
  typeof UserInterfaceStateStore.getters;

// We need to know the type of the store's state as well, so type out that structure too
type RootState = {
  accounts: typeof AccountStore.state;
  accountUsers: typeof AccountUserStore.state;
  currentUser: typeof CurrentUserStore.state;
  documents: typeof DocumentStore.state;
  messages: typeof MessagesStore.state;
  permissions: typeof PermissionStore.state;
  ui: typeof UserInterfaceStateStore.state;
  users: typeof UserStore.state;
};

// Declare the store's getter payload. If you're gonna have `modules` declared, then the getters will be set at runtime.
// Use an empty object here to avoid duplicate-key errors
const getters = {} as RootGetters & GettersImpl<RootState, RootGetters>; // Note the intersect

const { store, moduleActionContext, moduleGetterContext } = createDirectStore({
  modules: {
    accounts: AccountStore,
    accountUsers: AccountUserStore,
    currentUser: CurrentUserStore,
    currentAccount: CurrentAccountStore,
    documents: DocumentStore,
    messages: MessagesStore,
    permissions: PermissionStore,
    ui: UserInterfaceStateStore,
    users: UserStore
  },
  getters // Explicitly add our getters to the root store
});

export default store;
export type State = typeof store.state;
export type Getters = typeof store.getters; // This should now be populated correctly!
```

My latest working theory is that direct-vuex relies on `GettersImpl<State, Getters>` being well-typed. For some reason, TypeScript cannot infer that from our complex module structure, so we need to hint it along.

It's quite a lot of boilerplate, and new store modules need to be inserted in more places, not to mention existing modules with getters need to be added to the `RootGetters` type and `getters` object, but at least we get full typing in components this way.

I'll update this answer if I discover a more concise way to get this effect.